# deploy a machine (with qcow2 image) on KVM automatically via Terraform

Tags: terraform, kvm

I am new to terraform and i am trying to deploy a machine (with qcow2 image) on KVM automatically via Terraform.
i found this tf file:

```
provider "libvirt" {
  uri = "qemu:///system"
}

#provider "libvirt" {
#  alias = "server2"
#  uri   = "qemu+ssh://root@192.168.100.10/system"
#}

resource "libvirt_volume" "centos7-qcow2" {
  name = "centos7.qcow2"
  pool = "default"
  source = "https://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2"
  #source = "./CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2"
  format = "qcow2"
}

# Define KVM domain to create
resource "libvirt_domain" "db1" {
  name   = "db1"
  memory = "1024"
  vcpu   = 1

  network_interface {
    network_name = "default"
  }

  disk {
    volume_id = "${libvirt_volume.centos7-qcow2.id}"
  }

  console {
    type = "pty"
    target_type = "serial"
    target_port = "0"
  }

  graphics {
    type = "spice"
    listen_type = "address"
    autoport = true
  }
}
```

my questions are:

1. (source) the path of my qcow file has to be localy on my computer ?
2. I have a KVM machine ip that i connected it remotely by its ip. where should i put this ip in this tf file?
3. when i did it manually, i run "virt manager", do i need to write it here anywhere?

thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. It can be https also.
2. Do you mean a KVM host that VMs will be created ? Then you need to configure remote kvm access on that host and in the uri section of provider block you need to write its ip.
   `uri   = "qemu+ssh://username@IP_OF_HOST/system"`
3. You dont need virt-manager when you use terraform. You should use terraform resources for managing VM.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/dmacvicar/libvirt/latest/docs

https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/tree/main/examples/v0.13

Comment: thanks. 2.but where I'm adding the password of the username I have specified?

Comment: and is it ok to write the network this way: network_name = "enp2s0f0.301:macvtap"

Comment: you can add ssh key without passphrase to target machine. so your client can access it without password.

Comment: i am downloading my qcow file in https, but it requires a user name and password to download it. how can I put it in the terraform file? @m303945